# how to change navigation bar title icon on xamarin.forms ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i want to change navigation bar title icon on my xamarin.forms ios application.You can find requested point at the attached image.[app_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJxcN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) on Xamarin.Forms. Since each `UIViewController` has its own `NavigationItem`, you should do this in your particular page which you want to modify its `LeftBarButtonItem`. Here is my Renderer for you referring to:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace UIBarButtomItemsForms.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            var navigationItem = NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;

            UIBarButtonItem leftItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("Image.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) =>
            {

            });

            navigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(leftItem, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Then on Forms you can use this `CustomPage`, please notice that you should make your `MainPage` wrapped in a `NavigationPage`: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Change the Back Button: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_back_button/